# Oracle Driver Error - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: oracle, driver

I have recently changed my Oracle 9 databse to a new database (still Oracle 9). I have an application that connects to the database. I have changed the configuration file to point to my new databases IP address. When I load my application I get the error below. Based on my research, it seems the issue is an out of date driver. My application used to use classes12_01.zip. I have now replaced this driver with ojdbc14.jar. I am still getting this error. I believe I am able to create the driver correctly. The issue happens when My driver tries to find my new database in the connection pool. It says it doesn't exist.

Has anyone got a solution to my problem.

```
    Wed Mar 21 11:44:18 GMT+00:00 2012:<E> <JDBC Pool> Failed to create connection pool "xxxPool"
weblogic.common.ResourceException: weblogic.common.ResourceException:
Could not create pool connection. The DBMS driver exception was:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
        at oracle.security.o3logon.C1.r(C1)
        at oracle.security.o3logon.C1.l(C1)
        at oracle.security.o3logon.C0.e(C0)
        at oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(O3LoginClientHelper)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.O3log.<init>(O3log.java:287)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:227)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:198)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:251)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:224)
```

Comment: I created a test app and am able to connect to my new database using the same ojdbc14.jar so it nor makes the sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your driver ought to be the best match of JDK and Oracle version you can find.

ojbbc14.jar is still very much out of date.  JDK 7 is the standard today.

WebLogic is certified with a particular JDK version when you install it.  Which version of WebLogic are you using?  Which JDK is it certified for?  Which version of Oracle?

With all three of those answers in hand, you can select a JDBC driver.  But not before.  Both of your classes12 and ojbdc14 choices are likely to be incorrect.

I'm guessing that WebLogic is using JDK6, so you should get ojdbc6.jar for your version of Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I cannot find a lter version of the ojdbc jar. The Oracle website only has 0jdbc14.jar. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc9201-092698.html

Comment: Wrong.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: So you are suggesting I use a jar that was built for a later version of oracle that I am currently using?

Comment: I think my answer is clear: match the JDBC driver JAR version to your JDK and Oracle version.  Are you saying that your version of Oracle is so old that it doesn't have a JDBC driver newer than 14?  Post the WebLogic, JDK, and Oracle versions you're using.

Comment: Weblogic + JDK using  1.5.0_16-b02 and Oracle is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: I have replaced ojdbc14.jar with ojdbc5.jar and the issue persists. I also tried ojdbc6.jar and it's the same error.

Comment: The Oracle site says to use ojdbc14.jar for 9.2.0.8. So should I revert to using classes12.zip?

Comment: Ok, I don't know what version of java my weblogic is using... Got that wrong.. I don't have a registry.xml file to check.. Or a weblogic.jar to find the version via the java command.. Any ideas?

Comment: WebLogic Server (5.1.0 Service Pack 8 12/20/2000 16:34:54 #95137)

Comment: A 12 year old version of WebLogic?  You're 7 versions behind the current standard.  You might be using JDK 1.2; classes12.zip might be entirely correct for you.  A JAR upgrade won't fix this, but a WebLogic upgrade would help.  What version of Oracle?  8i?

Comment: Oracle is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.4.0. I cannot upgrade Weblogic right now so I'll have to make do. What I don't understand is that if I keep my old classes12.zip and revert to my old Oracle databse (still is 9i) it works..

Comment: Now I'm confused.  You had a problem, so you dug in and found out that your JDBC JAR was out of date, so you replaced it.  You put in a new JAR and it fails.  Then you put the old JAR back and it works?  Did you just put the new JAR into place, thinking that it was the right thing to do, before testing the new database with it?

Comment: No. I changed database connections and the app failed. I then tried replacing the classes12.zip with variations of ojdbc.jar. The issue still persisted. I have solved the problem. In my weblogic start up script, there was a hardcoded classpath. I added my ojdbc14.jar to the front of this path and it worked. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Ah!  Very good.  I'm glad you have your answer.  Do think about upgrading.  Your application is at risk.